# Determining whether the function is exponential?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Because the $x$-value is an exponent, then this must be an exponential function. By definition, an **exponential function** is where the independent variable (the $x$-value) is the exponent.

To write the function in the form $K(x) = ab^x$, I first converted the radical into its exponent form and moved the denominator over to the numerator to get

> $K(x) = (3^x)(3^{-\frac{1}{2}})(6^{-x})$

I then simplified it further, following the exponent rules of $a^ma^n = a^{m + n}$

> $K(x) = (3^{x - \frac{1}{2}})(6^{-x})$

However, as shown, my answers were incorrect. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Isn't it of the form $ab^x$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Because the x-value is an exponent, then this must be an exponential function. By definition, an exponential function is where the independent variable (the x-value) is the exponent.

While you're not wrong in this respect, this only really holds if the function is in its simplest form. Consider, for instance,

$$f(x) = \frac{3^x}{3^x}$$

Sure, the variable $x$ is only in exponents here. However, if you simplify, you realize immediately $f(x) = 1$, which is obviously not exponential.

So we have to be very careful about how we define things as a result of things like these. We define $f$ to be an exponential function if there exist constants $a,b$ such that $f(x) = ab^x$. To show a function is exponential, then, you need to somehow manipulate it into that form and determine the constants $a,b$ necessary.

To reiterate: **this is the real definition of an exponential function.** (Well, to an extent; there are modifications to the definition you can make, but this is the most relevant one for your case.) The notion of "$x$ appears in the exponent" is an intuition, but clearly doesn't always hold.

---

So, with this mind, we need to figure out what constants $a,b$ you need for

$$f(x) = \frac{3^x}{\sqrt 3 \cdot 6^x}$$

Well, first note that, through exponent rules,

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \cdot \frac{3^x}{6^x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \cdot \left( \frac 3 6 \right)^x = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \cdot \left( \frac 1 2 \right)^x$$

With this manipulation, it's clear what your constants $a,b$ are, and thus you can conclude that $f$ is exponential.

Again, be very careful about what $a,b$ can be: this is where you went wrong. They have to be constants, not functions themselves. $3^{x-0.5}$ is not a constant. Basically, you cannot have your constants depend on $x$.

Comment: What about a function like $q(r) = \frac{-8}{5^r}$? If I were to manipulate it into the form $f(x) = ab^x$, then I could do $q(r) =(-8)(5^{-r})$ and this would be an exponential function because *a* and *b* are constants. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, precisely. If you want to insist on the exponent being positive, you can also write that as 

$$q(r) = (-8) \left( \frac 1 5 \right)^r$$

which makes it clearer what the constants $a,b$ are. But yeah you have the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

We have $K(x) = \frac{3^x}{\sqrt{3}\cdot6^x} = (\frac{3}{6})^x\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = (\frac{1}{2})^x \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, so $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $b = \frac{1}{2}$.